# NetWare: MGET filenames which contains multiple dots from FTP server

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm trying to download a file from an FTP using a script:

Script.bat

```
ftp -s:DownloadFiles.ftp
```

DownloadFiles.ftp

```
open ftp_server
user
pass
ascii
prompt
lcd D:\LocalPath
mget  "File.*.TXT_T;1"
```

When I run the Script.bat I get the following error:

> 550-Failed to open CV0:[user]File^^^.20171104_024043.TXT_T; for input
>   . 550 file not found

According to this [link](https://support.novell.com/docs/Tids/Solutions/10057274.html), the problem seems to be that the file name contains multiple dots and the `mget` command will not found the file. Updating the server might solve the problem but I can't do that.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Why aren't you just using the regular GET command? Who is using an 18 plus year old Netware server?

Comment: Because I'm trying to download multiple files. As far as I know, get command only downloads one file. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Usually use `MGET` when you are trying to download multiple files with the same file mask. example: `file*.txt`.  Which would grab all text files that start with the word file.  You are not using any wildcards.  If you know what the file names are then just use `GET`.

Comment: You're right. Actually, I'm using a wildcard in my real scenerio. I updated the answer.

Comment: Or get a listing of all files first then dynamically write a second script to get the individual files by name one at a time.